# Categoricity of theory expressing a certain kind of equivalence relation

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider the language $\mathcal{L}$ of first-order logic equipped with a single binary relation symbol $R$. Let $\Gamma$ denote the theory expressing that $R$ is an equivalence relation such that there is exactly one equivalence class of size $n$ for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

> Is it the case that $\Gamma$ is $\kappa$-categorical for every
>   uncountable cardinal $\kappa$?

I've been unable to make progress in determining the answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This theory is complete, but not $\kappa$-categorical. The conditions don't say anything about the number of infinite equivalence classes, so you can construct two models, one with a single infinite equivalence class, the other with $\kappa$-many such classes. These are clearly not isomorphic, so the theory is not categorical.

In fact, for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$ and every model M of cardinality $\leq \kappa$ we can find an elementary extension $N_\kappa$ of $M$ with $\kappa$ infinite equivalence classes and with each infinite equivalence class having cardinality $\kappa$. This extension is unique up to isomorphism for each cardinal $\kappa$, so the theory is complete.

Comment: Thank you. In your second paragraph, are you tacitly using a well-known theorem to conclude that the theory is complete, or does it follow from an elementary argument (which I'm not seeing)?

Comment: The latter. If you had a model in which $\varphi$ holds, and one in which $\neg \varphi$ holds, both of cardinality $\kappa$, then one of them would not admit $N_\kappa$ as an elementary extension.

Comment: Got it. You've already answered my original question, but if you'd be willing to sketch how we construct $N_{\kappa}$, that would be great.

Comment: I'm sure you've figured it out already, but one way to prove it is by extending the language with a constant symbol $c_(x,0)$ for each $x < \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the number of equivalence classes in $M$. Then add constants $c_(x,y)$ for every $x < \kappa$ and $y < \kappa$, along with axioms $c_(x,i) \sim c_(x,j)$ for each $x,i,j$.

The resulting theory is consistent (because all its finite subsets are consistent), so it has a model (of size $\kappa$ by LS). This model contains $M$ as an elementary substructure.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Just a small correction. It's not clear from the construction you give that the resulting model has the property that every equivalence class has cardinality $\kappa$. When you find a model by compactness, it might have new equivalence classes of size smaller than $\kappa$. But if you repeat your construction $\omega$-many times, building an elementary chain, you'll get what you want, since then each equivalence class had to be added at some point in the chain.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Why must every equivalence class be added if we repeat $\omega$ many times?

Comment: I mean that if $M$ is the union of an increasing chain of structures, for any equivalence class in $M$, if $m$ is a representative of that class, then $m$ is an element of some structure $M_i$ in the chain. Based on Z.A.K.'s construction, the equivalence class of $m$ is blown up to size $\kappa$ in $M_{i+1}$, so it has size $\kappa$ in $M$.